# Axios. Spring MVC returns a 415 response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, axios

I am using Vue.js, axios and Spring.

On the page I have the following axios code

```
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user/info',
        params: {
            '_csrf' : document.getElementById('csrf_id').value,
            'name' : 'job',
            'age' : '25',
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    });
```

And on the server I have a receiving method like this

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class UserInfo {

        @ResponseBody
        @PostMapping(value = "/info", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", produces = "application/json" + ";charset=utf8")
        public String info(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name, @RequestParam(value = "age") String age) {

            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(age);

            return "ok";
        }
    }
```

Axios makes a request to the server, but the **server returns a 415 response**.
The request headers are missing the **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type. I suspect the problem lies precisely in this.

Tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpMethod Post is a method of writing and transmitting data in the request body.

In your case, you put data through `params`. If you execute code as you write, data will be sent such as `/user/info?_csrf=value&name=job&age=25` and there will be no data in the request body.

To get the response you want, you can modify it as below.

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user/info',
        data: '_csrf=csrf&name=job&age=25',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
     });
```

change `params` keyword to `data` and write data like querystring.